# How can I get the unique solution?

Tags: programming, canonicalization

The eight queens puzzle has 92 distinct solutions. If solutions that differ only by the symmetry operations of rotation and reflection of the board are counted as one, the puzzle has 12 solutions.

My code gives 24 unique solutions, how can I fix it, or is there any better method?

```
Length[sols=Cases[Permutations[Range[8]],{a_,b_,c_,d_,e_,f_,g_,h_}/;
      a+1!=b+2!=c+3!=d+4!=e+5!=f+6!=g+7!=h+8 && a-1!=b-2!=c-3!=d-4!=e-5!=f-6!=g-7!=h-8]]

Length[DeleteDuplicates[sols, #+#2==Table[9,8]||#==Reverse[#2]||Reverse[#]+#2==Table[9,8]&]]
```

Comment: Have you counted rotations?

Comment: About "better method"... If you means faster, just hardcode the answer.

Comment: I don't like a hardcode answer, efficiency is not important here.

Comment: `PermutationProduct` may be useful: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZBNSwMxFEX3@RWXBLrxoTR@VSRQV@Ju0O5CFpk2asDpQEwFmc5vH19msCBIN92em/fueWl8fg@Nz3Hth6Gr54Ra9zDoBIDuksBEE64I14Qbwi1h0dMYMp7yv2HJ@ntRpbjNViicQWkYg5WvP4K94ycO@z1UYc/hK6TPYJUeWRk9IPfv5MxOjk6434oqpGaX@YR2W6V2s1szO@5@RN2VwoeU/LdVmJVKLpqaYCHrOf@NkIRV@5IZvi0fU9xwMjk@vdpojCKpJMlz6QhdpEXP2rhYgocP2uMyffqyYfgB "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: Alternatively you can create the matrix and use `Transpose` (which is equivalent to the `PermutationProduct` approach above).

Comment: @mathe: I think you missed the 180 degree rotation symmetry, which is not the same as mirroring both axes. I have code to show the details if you're interested. After adding it i'm left with exactly 12 cases.

Comment: A Demonstration of this is in MAthWorld. [Click Here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EightQueensPuzzle/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's start with the original 92 cases:

```
Length[sols = Cases[
    Permutations[Range[8]], {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_} /;
    a + 1 != b + 2 != c + 3 != d + 4 != e + 5 != f + 6 != g + 7 != h + 8 &&
    a - 1 != b - 2 != c - 3 != d - 4 != e - 5 != f - 6 != g - 7 != h - 8
]]
```

> 92

To make reasoning about symmetries a bit easier let's write a function to convert to matrix representation

```
QueenMatrix[sol_] := Normal@SparseArray[Thread[Transpose[{Range[8], sol}] -> 1]]
```

which means we can now visualize our solutions, e.g.

```
MatrixPlot@QueenMatrix@sols[[1]]
```

[image: first eight queens solution]

Now find all the symmetries that we can apply in terms of the matrix representation:

```
g = MatrixPlot[#1, PlotLabel -> #2] & @@@ 
    With[{m = QueenMatrix@sols[[1]]},
     {{m, "Original"},
      {Reverse@m, "Mirror Rows"},
      {Reverse /@ m, "Mirror Columns"},
      {Reverse[Reverse /@ m], "Rotate 180\[Degree]"},
      {Transpose[m], "Mirror at Main Diagonal"},
      {Table[m[[i, Length[m] - j + 1]], {j, Length[m]}, {i,Length[m]}], "Rotate Left 90\[Degree]"},
      {Table[m[[Length[m] - i + 1, j]], {j, Length[m]}, {i,Length[m]}], "Rotate Right 90\[Degree]"},
      {Table[m[[Length[m] - i + 1, Length[m] - j + 1]], {j, Length[m]}, {i,Length[m]}], "Mirror at Anti-Diagonal"}
     }
    ] // Partition[#, 4] & // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: Symmetries overview]

After verifying they all make sense we can turn this into a function which checks if two solution matrices fall under any of those symmetry relations:

```
CheckMatrixSymmetries[mat1_, mat2_] := EqualTo[#2] /@ {
  Reverse@#,
  Reverse /@ #,
  Reverse[Reverse /@ #],
  Transpose[#],
  Table[#[[i, Length[#] - j + 1]], {j, Length[#]}, {i, Length[#]}],
  Table[#[[Length[#] - i + 1, j]], {j, Length[#]}, {i, Length[#]}],
  Table[#[[Length[#] - i + 1, Length[#] - j + 1]], {j, Length[#]}, {i, Length[#]}]
} &[mat1, mat2] // Apply[Or]
```

Now we can do the original case reduction with `DeleteDuplicates` in terms of our matrix symmetry checker

```
Length[
  sols3 = DeleteDuplicates[
    sols, 
    CheckMatrixSymmetries @@ (QueenMatrix /@ {#1, #2}) &
  ]
]
```

> 12

to find the unique solutions

```
Partition[MatrixPlot@*QueenMatrix /@ sols3, 4] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: All 12 unique solutions]

### Visualization of the solution symmetry group

As a bonus let's look at the adjacency graph created by our `CheckMatrixSymmetries` function with the help of `GraphPlot`:

```
GraphPlot[
  (* creates our adjacency matrix *)
  Outer[Boole@*CheckMatrixSymmetries, #, #, 1] &[QueenMatrix /@ sols],
  VertexLabeling -> True,
  VertexRenderingFunction -> (Inset[
    MatrixPlot[
      QueenMatrix@sols[[#2]],
      FrameTicks -> None, Mesh -> All, Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 40
    ],
    #1
  ]&),
  ImageSize -> 660
]
```

You can see that most unique solutions belong to a group of eight similar solutions obtained by our mirroring and rotation symmetries. The only exception being the last group of four, which due to their inherent 180 degree rotation symmetry collapses to only four different solutions. Those are also my favorite! :)

[image: Visualize Queen solutions symmetry graph]

Answer (score 4):

Your solutions give the rank of the Queen for each file. So, a simple rotation corresponds to a permutation of `{8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}` by the solution:

```
rotate[solution_] := Permute[Reverse @ Range[8], solution]
```

Let's see this in action:

```
sols[[1]]
rotate @ sols[[1]]
```

> {1, 5, 8, 6, 3, 7, 2, 4}
>
> {8, 2, 4, 1, 7, 5, 3, 6}

Or using a variant of @ThiesHeideke's visualization function:

```
QueenMatrix[sol_] := MatrixPlot[
    SparseArray[Thread[Transpose@{sol,Range[8]}->1]],
    Mesh->True,
    DataReversed->{True,False}
]

QueenMatrix[sol[[1]]]->QueenMatrix[rotate@sol[[1]]]
```

[image]

Next, a reflection corresponds to a reverse:

```
reflect[solution_] := Reverse[solution]
```

Another visualization:

```
QueenMatrix[sols[[1]]] -> QueenMatrix[reflect[sols[[1]]]]
```

[image]

So, using `rotate` and `reflect` we can canonicalize each solution:

```
canon[solution_] := First @ Sort @ Join[
    NestList[rotate, solution, 3],
    NestList[rotate, reflect@solution, 3]
]
```

The unique solutions are then given by:

```
DeleteDuplicates[canon /@ sols]
% //Length
```

> {{1, 5, 8, 6, 3, 7, 2, 4}, {1, 6, 8, 3, 7, 4, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 3, 1, 7, 
>     5}, {2, 5, 7, 1, 3, 8, 6, 4}, {2, 5, 7, 4, 1, 8, 6, 3}, {2, 6, 1, 7, 4, 8, 
>     3, 5}, {2, 6, 8, 3, 1, 4, 7, 5}, {2, 7, 3, 6, 8, 5, 1, 4}, {2, 7, 5, 8, 1, 
>     4, 6, 3}, {3, 5, 2, 8, 1, 7, 4, 6}, {3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 7, 2, 6}, {3, 6, 2, 5, 
>     8, 1, 7, 4}}
>
> 12

Answer (score 2):

I think we should consider a more general case.

How to reduce the elements of list by a **Group**.

I've written such a function before.

```
cyc2rul[Cycles[M_]]:=Flatten[Rule@@@Partition[#,2,1,1]&/@M]
Options[cycReduce]={Orderless->True};
cycReduce[inlist_,cyc_,OptionsPattern[]]:=
  Block[{i=1,list=inlist,l,rul,del},
      l=Length[Transpose@@cyc];
      rul=cyc2rul[cyc];
      Catch@Quiet@While[i>0,
          del=Rest@NestList[#/.rul&,Check[list[[i++]],Throw[list]],l-1];
          del=If[OptionValue[Orderless],Sort/@del,del];
          list=DeleteCases[Alternatives@@del][list];
      ]
 ]
```

---

First encode the `sols` to the `board numbers`.

```
sols=Select[Permutations[n=Range@8],And@@Unequal@@@{#+n,#-n}&];
enc=MapIndexed[#+8(First[#2]-1)&,#]&/@sols
```

[image]

Numbered from the top left corner, `{1,5,8,6,3,7,2,4}` becomes `{1,13,24,30,35,47,50,60}` now.

There're 4 symmetrical groups and 1 rotation group.

```
MatrixForm[m=Array[8(#1-1)+#2&,{8,8}]]
groups={
  {m,Reverse/@m},           (*"Mirror at Columns"*)
  {m,Reverse@m},            (*"Mirror at Rows"*)
  {m,Transpose[m]},         (*"Mirror at Main Diagonal"*)
  {m,ConjugateTranspose[m]},(*"Mirror at Conjugate Diagonal"*)
  NestList[Transpose@Reverse@#&,m,3](*"Rotate"*)
};
```

Then do the group reduce and get:

```
toC[mat_]:=Cycles[Union[Flatten[Transpose[mat,{3,1,2}]/.{a_,a_}->Nothing,1],SameTest->(Sort@#1==Sort@#2&)]];
Length[redu=Fold[cycReduce,enc,toC/@groups]]
```

Wait...there're 14 solutions...what's going wrong.

```
dec=MapIndexed[#+8(1-First[#2])&,#]&/@redu
{{1,5,8,6,3,7,2,4},{1,6,8,3,7,4,2,5},{2,4,6,8,3,1,7,5},
 {2,5,7,1,3,8,6,4},{2,5,7,4,1,8,6,3},{2,6,1,7,4,8,3,5},
 {2,6,8,3,1,4,7,5},{2,7,3,6,8,5,1,4},{2,7,5,8,1,4,6,3},
 {3,5,7,1,4,2,8,6},{3,5,8,4,1,7,2,6},{3,6,2,5,8,1,7,4},
 {3,6,2,7,1,4,8,5},{3,6,2,7,5,1,8,4}
}
```

Last two havn't been reduced, seems I lost some symmetries.

`cycReduce[list,{cyc1,cyc2...}] != Fold[cycReduce,list,{cyc1,cyc2...}]`

Glad to see if anyone can help solve this problem.

[Reduce lists under permutation group](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161693/reduce-lists-under-permutation-group)

Comment: I think the problem is with `ConjugateTranspose`, which doesn't "mirror at conjugate diagonal" but does a regular transpose and then takes the complex conjugate (which does nothing for an all-real matrix). The least verbose substitute I can find is `Reverse@Transpose@Reverse`.