# How to generate all $ 3 \times 3 $ matrices with $ a,a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c $？

Tags: matrix

How to generate all $ 3 \times 3 $ matrices with $ a,a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c $, which can not be obtained from each other by rotation transformation?

Comment: Is this different from doing `res = Permutations[{a, a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c}];
res = ArrayReshape[#, {3, 3}] & /@ res;
MatrixForm[#] & /@ res`? To check for the last part `which can not be obtained each other by rotation transformation` is something not included in the above code. How would you check for this part?

Comment: @Nasser  Yes, it is different. I want to classify these matrices. If the matrices that can be obtained by rotation of one matrix，we will think they are the same category.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "rotation transformation" in this case?

Comment: Whether two diagonalizable matrices can be unitarily transformed into each other if fully defined by their spectrum. If the spectrum is the same, it's possible; otherwise, it is not. You can generate matrices as @Nasser recommends and then filter them numerically by taking a few specific values of a,b,c using Eigenvalues.

Comment: @mmeent It means that the central element of the matrix is the axis of rotation. If we rotate the matrix [1,2,3;1,2,3;1,2,3] by ninety degrees, we will get [3,3,3;2,2,2;1,1, 1]

Comment: Related link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161296/5379

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A brute force approach:

For a permutation `p`, `protations[p]` constructs the union of permutations obtained by all possible ***two-step*** rotations of its 8 elements after dropping its middle element. We use `MemberQ[protations[#], #2]&` as the test function in `DeleteDuplicates`. Then using `Partition[#, 3]&` for all permutations in the resulting list gives the desired list of  3X3 matrices.

```
lst = {a, a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c};
perms = Permutations[{a, a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c}];

Length @ perms
```

> 1260

Borrowing the idea that we can consider the last element of permutation as the center of the matrix from @jose's answer:

```
ClearAll[protations]
protations[x_] := Module[{l = Length[x]}, 
  Union @ (RotateRight[Most @ x, #] & /@ Range[0, l - 2, 2])]

dupetest = MemberQ[protations[#], Most @ #2] &;

out = DeleteDuplicates[perms, dupetest];

Length @ out
```

> 318

10 examples:

```
Row[MatrixForm[Partition[Insert[Most@#, Last@#, 5], 3]] & /@ RandomSample[out, 10]]
```

[image]

An alternative test function using `GroupOrbits` (again from jose's answer) of the `PermutationGroup` of a subset of the group elements of [`CyclicGroup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CyclicGroup.html):

```
pg = PermutationGroup[GroupElements[CyclicGroup[8]][[;; ;; 2]]]

dupetest2 = MemberQ[First@GroupOrbits[pg, {Most@#}, Permute], Most@#2] &;

out2 = DeleteDuplicates[perms, dupetest2];

out2  == out
```

> True

A much faster approach is to generate `GroupOrbits` of `pg` for `perms` at once (again from jose's answer) and take the first element of each orbit.

```
out3 = GroupOrbits[pg, perms, Permute][[All, 1]];

out3 == out
```

> True

Comment: Thank you! What does “@Range[-7,7]” mean in the code?

Comment: @King.Max,` RotateRight[list, -k]` is the same as `RotateLeft[list, k]` (rotate to the left k positions).  `RotateRight[{a, b, c, d}, #] & /@ Range[-3, 3]` gives list of all possible rotations of the 4 element list `{a, b, c, d}`.

Comment: Same as the question I asked below: if one of the matrices is like this：$\left(\begin{array}{lll}{1} & {2} & {3} \\ {8} & {9} & {4} \\ {7} & {6} & {5}\end{array}\right)$ . I know that such a matrix $\left(\begin{array}{lll}{3} & {4} & {5} \\ {2} & {9} & {6} \\ {1} & {8} & {7}\end{array}\right)$ will be treated the same. But such a matrix $\left(\begin{array}{lll}{2} & {3} & {4} \\ {1} & {9} & {5} \\ {8} & {7} & {6}\end{array}\right)$ ,I don't want it to be considered the same. Will it be considered as the same matrix in your code and deleted?

Comment: I mean, when a matrix is rotated 90,180，270 or 360degrees, we think it is equivalent, and the other we think they are not equivalent.

Comment: @King.Max, this is important piece of information; you should add this to your question. As is, both answers consider the third matrix sames as the first two. You can change `Range[0, l - 2]` in `protations` to `Range[0, l - 2, 2]` to handle equivalence by  "90,180，270 or 360 Degree" rotations.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 6):

Let me give a GroupOrbits approach, imitating many aspects of the accepted solution. Start again with all permutations of the elements:

```
list = {a, a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c};
perms = Permutations[list];
```

Again, assume each permutation defines a matrix whose central element is placed last:

```
makeMatrix[{e1_, e2_, e3_, e4_, e5_, e6_, e7_, e8_, e9_}] := {{e1, e2, e3}, {e8, e9, e4}, {e7, e6, e5}}
```

Then we can partition the lists into orbits of equivalent cases under cyclic permutation of the first eight elements:

```
In[]:= Length[orbits = GroupOrbits[CyclicGroup[8], perms, Permute]]
Out[]= 159
```

Select some examples of orbit representatives with

```
MatrixForm /@ makeMatrix /@ First /@ RandomSample[orbits, 10]
```

Comment: But I have a problem: if one of the matrices is like this：$\left(\begin{array}{lll}{1} & {2} & {3} \\ {8} & {9} & {4} \\ {7} & {6} & {5}\end{array}\right)$ . I know that such a matrix $\left(\begin{array}{lll}{3} & {4} & {5} \\ {2} & {9} & {6} \\ {1} & {8} & {7}\end{array}\right)$ will be treated the same. But such a matrix $\left(\begin{array}{lll}{2} & {3} & {4} \\ {1} & {9} & {5} \\ {8} & {7} & {6}\end{array}\right)$ ,I don't want it to be considered the same. Will it be considered as the same matrix in your code and deleted?

Comment: To consider that situation you need a different permutation group: instead of using CyclicGroup[8], use PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,3,5,7}, {2,4,6,8}}]}]. There are then 318 different orbits, because each of the previous 159 orbits breaks in two.

Comment: Thanks for your help!